# Can I a buy a new PC with minimal fan noise?

Tags: laptop, fan

I currently own a Lenovo Yoga 710 with a 7th Generation Intel Core i7 with 8 GB RAM. However, the fan inside this laptop is constantly on and is loud. Even if I just open a simple application like Notepad++, the fan quickly turns on at near-maximum capacity.

After reading [this](https://www.coolblue.nl/en/advice/silent-laptop.html), I suspect that the constant fan noise is because my laptop contains an i7. I am not sure if this is true. I am also thinking about buying a new laptop, but I want to make sure that it has minimal fan noise. Should I limit myself to an i5?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look why CPU is running so much.

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon i7 and the CPU runs at <5% more than 95% of the time. The fan is almost inaudible. It has a 1 TB MVNe SSD and that is silent of course.

Look through Startup (Task Manager) to see what is starting.

From Microsoft SysInternals, get both Autoruns and Process Explorer.  Run both.

In Autoruns, see what has started and make sure it is all valid.

In Process Explorer, see what processes are taking so much CPU.

Use Windows Defender to do a full scan for Viruses.

8 GB is completely adequate for Windows 10 64-bit. If you have a memory hungry task, you might need more.

An i7 is a good processor and not prone to running too much. Look through the list above for other problems.

Make sure your Power Settings are all Normal (reset them to default).

Answer (score 0):

i5 are a decent choice for a balanced laptop. i7 are more power hungry and your battery usually go down faster, generates more heat and that makes fans go faster and noisier. 8 GB RAM is fine, and SSD is a must: less mechanical parts than a conventional disk makes them low energy consuming, silent and cooler.
Without going into much detail here (I can clarify more if you want), you're right.